# Lua Scope for Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was wondering How I might be able to access Obj.isActive from an outside function such as "Object:setActive()".  I would pull it up to the Object table However i need multiple instances of the isActive property for all the individual Objects.  Just trying to figure out a way to do so.

### Object

```
Object = {};

ObjectMeta = {__index = Object};

function Object.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Obj.isActive= false;
    return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta);
end

function Object:setActive()
    --??????????????????????????
    --self.isActive = nil
end
return Object;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metatables, you can use `self` as follows:

```
function Object:setActive()
    self.isActive = true
end
```

Here is a SSCCE for your code: http://eval.in/25148

Comment: if i do as you say, unfortunately self.isActive = nil and gives me incorrect responses.  This is one of the issues Ive been running into with this